# Getting error even after including webdriver jar in JMeter

Tags: webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I get error even after including **jmeter-plugins-webdriver-1.1.3.jar** in JMeter, While clicking on jp@gc firefox driver config it still shows me the error dialog box as mentioned below

[image: Error in using webdriver plugin in jmeter]

Please suggest me some options in order to use selenium webdriver with jmeter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the goal of using Selenium Webdriver with Jmeter?

Comment: As i saw in a webpage using that plugin one can write test as we do in webdriver inside jmeter.

Comment: https://udayhere.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-in-jmeter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you're missing Selenium libraries in JMeter classpath.

- **JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar** - should go to %JMETER_HOME%/lib/ext
- everything else from [JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.3.zip](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.3.zip) should go to %JMETER_HOME%/lib

If you drop JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.3.zip to the folder where your JMeter lives and just unpack it - everything should be fine.

JMeter restart is required to load the jars.

See [Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) guide for more details.

Comment: thanks Dmitri, can you send some other links to download it. I am getting 404 error with that link.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel. It works for me. Can you open http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/ and select JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.3.zip ?

Comment: sorry to say, in my office they have blocked the downloads which has more than 10 mb.

Answer (score 1):

your jmeter-plugins-webdriver-1.1.3.jar needs to be located in folder lib/ext

Comment: yes like that way only i have done it.